problemas con la ejecución de una función en Google cloud functions
Estoy intentando ejecutar una función dentro de cloud function que en teoría debería ser capaz de consultar las respuestas de un google forms y almacenar el archivo von las respuestas dentro de un bucket de cloud storage  (Esto necesito que lo haga de manera automática. Se que hay algo mal con el código en cuanto a las credenciales de mi cuenta de ser vicio por que el (Estado de HTTP: 400) que me tira la prueba luego de ejecutarla hace referencia a que no se logra hacer correctamente la consulta.
import pandas as pd
from googleapiclient import discovery
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from google.cloud import storage

SCOPES = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/forms.responses.readonly", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"]
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = "Aqui uso la URI de gsutil del archivo en cloud storage"
FORM_DISCOVERY_DOC = "https://forms.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v1"

FORM_ID = ""
BUCKET_NAME = ""
FILE_NAME = "form_responses.csv"

def get_form_responses():
    creds = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)
    form_service = discovery.build("forms", "v1", credentials=creds, discoveryServiceUrl=FORM_DISCOVERY_DOC, static_discovery=False)

    result = form_service.forms().responses().list(formId=FORM_ID).execute()

    responses = []
    for response in result["responses"]:
        answers = {}
        for answer in response["answers"].values():
            question_id = answer["questionId"]
            text_answers = [text_answer["value"] for text_answer in answer["textAnswers"]["answers"]]
            answers[question_id] = ", ".join(text_answers)
        responses.append(answers)

    return pd.DataFrame(responses)

def upload_to_storage(dataframe):
    client = storage.Client()
    bucket = client.bucket(BUCKET_NAME)
    blob = bucket.blob(FILE_NAME)
    blob.upload_from_string(dataframe.to_csv(index=False), content_type="text/csv")
    print(f"File uploaded to gs://{BUCKET_NAME}/{FILE_NAME}")

def main(request):
    df = get_form_responses()
    upload_to_storage(df)
    return "Process completed successfully."


Agrega el mensaje completo "HTTP: 400" por favor
